# Noob jquery .hide and .click question

Tags: jquery

I am a Jquery noob.  I and am trying to create an accordion menu.  I have been able to get the following js working with the following HTML code.

```
function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide();
  $('#menu li a').click(
    function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');   
      }
    );
  }
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

.

```
<li>                        
 <a href="#">Testing #1</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.php.net/">PHP</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/">Ruby</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Test #2</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.php.net/">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/">Ruby</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to to use table for each li.  I am not sure if this is the best way.  So far I have this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.link1.com/">Link-1</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.link2.com/">Link-2</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.link3.com/">Link-3</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </li>
```

Do I need to adjust my js to work in this scenario?  With the tables, it still appears to work, but I suspect I will be generating a lot more tags (Data) than needed to accomplish this.

Any helping or input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EQggD/). One suggestion though, you can shorten this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});​
```

Down to:

```
$(initMenu);​
```

When passing a function to [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) it attaches that function as a `document.ready` handler, and it'll execute when the page is good to go. 
[You can test that here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EQggD/1/), or the anonymous function version [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EQggD/2/):

```
$(function () {
  $('#menu ul').hide();
  $('#menu li a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');    
  });
});​
```

Comment: @Ethan - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers to your questions via the checkmark on the left of the one that best resolve the issue :)